# float arrays using functions and for loop

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops

I have a mere grasp of functions in C so bear with me. My first two functions are correct and probably the third one. The goal is to be able to output up to 100 assignments' grades when entering the points awarded and available in.

We were given a standard format of `char GradeFromTotalRawMarks(float marksAwarded[], float marksAvailable[], int maxAssignments);` . I keep getting the following error about pointers (which I have no knowledge of yet) and I don't know how to use max assignments, which should indicate the total number of assignments being passed to the function.

```
argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "float *" 'function':
cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage);
char GradeFromRawMarks(float marksAwarded, float marksAvailable);
char GradeFromTotalRawMarks(float marksAwarded[], float marksAvailable[], int maxAssignments);

int main()
{
    int maxAssignments;
    float MarksAwarded[100];
    float MarksAvailable[100];
    GradeFromTotalRawMarks(MarksAwarded[100], MarksAvailable[100], maxAssignments);

    return 0;
}
char GradeFromPercentage(float percentage)
{
    char grade;
    if (percentage >= 90)
    {
        grade = 'A';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 70)
    {
        grade = 'B';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 50)
    {
        grade = 'C';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 30)
    {
        grade = 'D';
    }
    else
    {
        grade = 'F';
    }
    return grade;
}

char GradeFromRawMarks(float marksAwarded, float marksAvailable)
{
    float percentage = (marksAwarded / marksAvailable) * 100;
    GradeFromPercentage(percentage);

    return GradeFromPercentage(percentage);
}
char GradeFromTotalRawMarks(float marksAwarded[], float marksAvailable[], int maxAssignments)
{
    char finish = 'n';
    int count1;
    while (finish == 'n')
    {
        for (count1 = 0; count1 < 100 && finish == 'n'; count1++)
        {       
            printf("Enter the marks awarded:");
            scanf("%f", &marksAwarded[count1]);
            printf("Enter the marks available: \n", &marksAvailable[count1]);
            scanf("%f", &marksAvailable[count1]);

            GradeFromRawMarks(marksAwarded[count1], marksAvailable[count1]);

            printf("If you have finished, type n.");
            scanf("%c", &finish);
        }
    }

    return GradeFromRawMarks(marksAwarded[count1], marksAvailable[count1]);
}
```

Comment: "I keep getting some errors about pointers". Would make sense to include those exact errors in the question right?

Comment: `MarksAwarded[100]` an out of bounds access. And you are supposed to pass the whole array to `GradeFromTotalRawMarks`, not a single float, Change that to `MarksAwarded`. Same for `MarksAvailable`.

Comment: argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "float *"


 'function': cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *'

Comment: Please put that error in the question not in comments. That error is telling you exactly what I mentioned. `MarksAwarded[100]` is a single `float`, whereas the function requires a `float *`.

Comment: aight imma give it a try

Comment: I get a run time check  failure #3

Comment: Unsubstantiated claims like "My first two functions are correct and probably the third one" tend to point to the first places to look for trouble.  Very often, the problem is that the code you believe is correct is actually incorrect, and the wrong belief/assumption leads to problems as you try to diagnose what's going on.

Comment: I have tested them and they're fine though

Comment: The call `GradeFromTotalRawMarks(MarksAwarded[100], MarksAvailable[100], maxAssignments);` is bogus; you probably need `GradeFromTotalRawMarks(MarksAwarded, MarksAvailable, maxAssignments);`, but I've not worked out where the arrays are initialized (beyond "it is not before you call this function, so it had better be in this function, or in the functions called from this function").  This call is why you are getting observations about the compilers about 'pointers' — arrays and pointers are closely related (but distinct) in C, and arrays are passed to functions as pointers.

Comment: The 'first function' defined is `main()` and it is not OK.  Or were you referring to the three functions that are declared before `main()` and you mean that all your problems are in `main()`?  It isn't clear, but most people would treat the declarations as 'incidental' (important, but incidental), and count the function definitions.  Precision is important in programming and in questions asked on SO.

Answer (score 1):

In your main function, check this line:

```
GradeFromTotalRawMarks(MarksAwarded[100], MarksAvailable[100], maxAssignments);
```

The first parameters are wrong. You are supposed to pass the whole array. 
Change that line to:

```
GradeFromTotalRawMarks(MarksAwarded, MarksAvailable, maxAssignments);
```

I compiled your code after fixing the above problem and it compiles without any error.